# rviz crashes at startup for universal robot

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-industrial, universal-robot, ur-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the hydro-devel-c-api branch of the universal_robot package from the ros-industrial github and am attempting to run the demonstration commands from the readme file. The python demonstration runs fine and controls the UR5 well. However, when I use the roslaunch ur5_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=false robot_ip:=IP_OF_THE_ROBOT command (with the proper ip address there), rviz begins to start, and then crashes. This is the terminal output from this command: pastebin.com/wTUu5xQN.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172793/rviz-crashes-at-startup-for-universal-robot/) by [airplanesrule](https://answers.ros.org/users/18786/airplanesrule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2014-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be related to the problem described in [Does anyone have a ur5 working with moveit and hydro?](http://answers.ros.org/question/128566/does-anyone-have-a-ur5-working-with-moveit-and-hydro/), and in particular to this comment:

> It would seem the UR5 MoveIt cfg uses a set of links, instead of a single chain, which is different from other ROS-I cfgs. I'm not sure why it is setup like that, there might be a valid reason.

As far as I know (and as @sedwards explained on the mailinglist), the `hydro-devel-c-api` branch hasn't been updated with the regenerated MoveIt configurations, which could explain why you are still seeing that crash.

A related bug report on the `universal_robot` github repository: [41: rviz crashes when trying to launch ur5_moveit_config in hydro](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/41).

Possibly related other ROS Answers question (and answer): [Problem with ikfast_moveit tutorial](http://answers.ros.org/question/151656/problem-with-ikfast_moveit-tutorial/?answer=154811#post-id-154811).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0